# sprintf causing timing-issues?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-c++

I'm experiencing a perculiar issue when using sprintf.

I need a char array to look like this: `g;cmd;arg;e;`, where arg gets leading zeros so it is always 3 chars long, and cmd gets leading zeros so it's always 15 chars long.
As an example, if cmd = 20 and arg = 3749, I need a char array looking like this: `g;020;000000000003749;e;`.
Both arg and cmd are integers.

I initially accomplished this in pretty inefficient way, but I changed it to something much simpler using sprintf because I needed my code to be faster. Both my initial code and my change can be found [on github](https://github.com/evertdespiegeleer/JAMES/commit/f9af9fcbfbaaca73431786b6f17a2cb707eed34b).

My current implementation looks like this:

```
#define cmdMsgLength 3
#define argMsgLength 15
#define totalFormatedMsgLength (2+cmdMsgLength+1+argMsgLength+3)
#define msgFormater "g;%03d;%015d;e;"

char msgToSendFormated[totalFormatedMsgLength];
void sendMsg(int _cmd, int _arg) {
 sprintf(msgToSendFormated, msgFormater, _cmd, _arg);
 Serial.print(msgToSendFormated);
}
```

This seemed to work well, until my uC also had to control 4 ESC's. I honestly can't find any relation between the two, but it seems like this implementation leads to problems with the ESC's, where of course timing is quite important. The ESC's are being programmed correctly, but when using the Arduino function servo.writeMicroseconds to actuate them, they seem to act randomly. After quite a lot of tests, only this change to my code seems to be causing the issue. As this piece code is so simple and the old code (check the github link) also used Serial.print, I assume sprintf is the culprit.

Is sprintf known to cause these sort of timing-issues? Could it be anything else?

Comment: Ain't you forgetting about the null terminator in your length calculation?

Comment: @JVApen, is a null terminator needed in this context? sprintf is new to me, but as the code actually sends what I expect over uart, I assumed I implemented it correctly. Are you saying msgToSendFormated should be 1 char larger?

Comment: sprintf will write it, as far as I'm aware, yes, that's indeed what I am saying

Comment: @JVApen that indeed worked. I should've researched sprintf a little more. Thank you so much!

Comment: If all you’re doing is sending it out Serial then it would be MUCH faster and more code efficient to just use several Serial.print statements in a row and send it out piece-meal like.  Since serial data is buffered and slow the actual transmission will be the same, the receiver will never know the difference.  It will be more lines, but much smaller code.  sprintf is a very expensive function.

Comment: @Delta_G I get where this is comming from but have a look at my original code, that’s exactly what it used to do. With my new method, the loop runs 3 times as fast (it went up from 11Hz to 29Hz on avg). If it weren’t for the (3 chars arg, 15 chars cmd)-scheme, I assume the old method would be more efficient indeed, but I need those leading zeroes. All suggestions are welcome, but it seems to me sprintf is the most efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: Your original code used pow.  That was the slow part.  Get rid of that and you can make that way faster than this.

Comment: Why are you writing so many characters for cmd anyway.  It is an int.  The longest it could ever possibly be is 5 characters long.  So ten of those 0's you can just print without having to calculate anything.  You know there will always be at least 10 0's in the cmd.

Comment: @Delta_G Hmm I'll have a look into that. The reason I used pow was to make it a little easier to parametrically change the length of the cmd part of the message, cause I knew I would be changing that in the future. I know the 15 chars are useless, but that's a temporary thing. The interpreter of the messages being sent currently needs these 15 chars, but I'm working on that. (https://git.io/JU8OU)

Answer (score 0):

As JVApen pointed out, sprintf always writes a null terminator. As msgToSendFormated was not long enough for that, I'd get an overflow. Setting `char msgToSendFormated[totalFormatedMsgLength + 1];` fixed the problem.